# Error on using pagination with Query annotation Spring Data JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, pagination, spring-data-jpa, jpql

```
@Repository
public interface PriceListDurationRepository extends CrudRepository<PriceListDuration, String> {

    String mQuery = "SELECT qplt, qplab"    
                     + " ,(SELECT iuomt1.unitOfMeasure FROM UnitsOfMeasureTransTbl iuomt1) "
                 + " FROM PriceListDuration qplab, PriceListDetail qplt " 
                 + " WHERE qplab.priceListId           =qplt.priceListId ";

    @Query(value = mQuery + " AND esib.itemNumber = :itemnumber")
    Page<PriceListDuration> getByItemNumber(String itemnumber, Pageable pageable);
}
```

I am using pagination in the getByItemNumber method. But it returns error because of the subquery at the column level.

If I remove the

```
Page<PriceListDuration> getByItemNumber(String itemnumber, Pageable pageable)
```

with `List<PriceListDuration> getByItemNumber(String itemnumber);` then it works. Seems pagination does not support subquery. Is there any alternate way to use pagination to this method ? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You may need `countQuery`, try:

```
@Query(value =  mQuery + " AND esib.itemNumber = :itemnumber",
    countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM (" + mQuery + " AND esib.itemNumber = :itemnumber" + ")",
    nativeQuery = true)
```

Also, you may also need to add `Order by`

Check a sample:

```
 @Query(
  value = "SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY id", 
  countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM Users", 
  nativeQuery = true)
Page<User> findAllUsersWithPagination(Pageable pageable);
```

It is from here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

Comment: Does countQuery works for nativeQuery = false. Your code works only if I change the return type to List from Page. But that would be a good idea

Comment: That is strange :) `Page` should be fine as return type.  Updated and provided a sample

Comment: I am querying from entities. Your approach is not working for nativeQuery = false

Comment: Works perfectly fine for nativeQuery with Page as a return type. My code uses Spring-data-jpa 2.2.6.RELEASE.